# How to use macbook storage space for linux kernel development from other linux machine?

Tags: macos, git, ubuntu, linux-kernel, storage

I have Macbook pro and HP Compaq mini(running ubuntu 14.04, used for testing custom kernel). Now what I need is, I want to have the whole linux source in macbook storage but need to work on that source from linux machine( HP Compaq in my case). So if something goes wrong while updating custom kernel I can still have the changes and local git branches.

```
I need something like this :
mount -t <FS> <SRC_DIR_IN_MAC> <WORK_DIR_IN_LINUX>    but how do I achieve this??
```

Note : I am aware of cross compilation of kernel, but that's not the solution I am looking for.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up NFS share on your Mac. [This article](http://www.barryodonovan.com/2012/12/12/apple-os-x-as-an-nfs-server-with-linux-clients) solves (and describes configuration of thereof) almost exactly the same problem.

That said, nicer solution would seem to be setting up git server on your Mac and push there your commits.